# mobaxterm doesn't connection

Tags: linux, mobaxterm

Mobaxterm doesn't connection through user session.

I set passphrase in sha key and after it mobaxterm doesn't connection .And i get error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent: publickey)

The strangest thing is that they don’t even ask me to enter passphrase...

And I think it's because i set passphrase.

If i connect using terminal everythink works

Comment: Did you send the public key to the machine that you are connecting to, allow Public Key Authentication in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and then restart the service?

Comment: @Nasir Riley.  did through graphic interface. As I usually do always, but without passphrase. https://imge.to/i/Po7uA. (for example ec2)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error from one MobaXterm (Professional Edition v21.4) with SSH session.
On the same MobaXterm, the ssh connection from its local terminal through command with same key works.
In another MobaXterm (personal edition v23.0), the saved session with same key works as expected

Target is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (OpenVPN AMI in AWS Market Place)

```
Apr 11 22:00:59 openvpn sshd[3239]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Apr 11 22:00:59 openvpn sshd[3239]: error: Received disconnect from 212.143.134.91 port 53972:14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

Googled the error message and found the solution: [SSH server gives "userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]" when connecting with Putty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721606/ssh-server-gives-userauth-pubkey-key-type-ssh-rsa-not-in-pubkeyacceptedalgorit)