# SSH server gives "userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]" when connecting with Putty

Tags: ssh, openssh, putty

I have built a new Ubuntu server in AWS. Now for some reason my private key that works on other Ubuntu servers is not working her . The error in auth.log is

`userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]`

This only is an issue with  Putty, if I try logging via a linux workstation no issues at all with any machine.

The difference I see is the new server is

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS running `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

The working (old) server is

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) running `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

Has something changed in this version of OpenSSH? How do I get putty working again?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404049/ssh-without-password-does-not-work-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-22-04 although the recommendation to re-enable rsa isn't the best.  it's probably best to switch crypto, see this for more details: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A simple solution.

Add this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Afterwards, restart the `sshd` service to make the new settings come into effect.

```shellsession
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  But what did work was upgrading putty from 0.74 to 0.78.

Comment: @user2449151 same for me. **Upgrading Putty** solved the problem on Windows 11.

Comment: `ssh-rsa` has been [deprecated and in fact, disabled by default for security reasons and should be avoided](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2). Use `rsa-sha2-256` or `rsa-sha2-512` instead.

Comment: Note to self: this worked for me too after updating putty

Comment: One little addition, this line should be written as `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa`

Answer (score 25):

There are several types of keys and signature algorithms in the SSH protocol.  RSA keys, which have the key type `ssh-rsa`, can be used to sign with SHA-1 (in which case, the signature type is `ssh-rsa`), SHA-256 (which has signature type `rsa-sha2-256`), or SHA-512 (which has signature type `rsa-sha2-512`).

What you're seeing here is that you're connecting with an RSA key and using the `ssh-rsa` signature type with SHA-1.  Unfortunately, SHA-1 is no longer secure, and the server is telling you that it won't accept that signature type.  This is the right thing to do, because it avoids any security problems.

You can solve this in a couple different ways.  First, you can simply upgrade PuTTY.  The latest version supports the SHA-2 signature algorithms (SHA-256 and SHA-512), and so things should just work.  You can also generate a different SSH key, say, an Ed25519 key, which is considered the most recommended option by Mozilla, GitHub, and other reputable parties.  Note that PuTTY classes these as EdDSA keys, which is the more generic term; you want the 255 or 256 bit option.

You could also adjust `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server side to include `ssh-rsa` (you should also include all of the other options in `ssh -Q sig` as well if you do this).  However, this means you're using insecure SHA-1 signatures and thus you probably want to choose one of the other options instead.

Answer (score 6):

*From the comments, but not enough visible, and before making trade-off with security, better to check if other simple methods works.*

Before to make any change on server side, try to update putty to the newest version. In my case, the version 0.78 solved the problem, without any changes on server side nor on keys.

I cannot find the real reason in the [Putty ChangeLog file](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/changes.html).

Comment: As also stated in the comments in the first answer, the problem is with PuTTY. This is also valid for Debian 12 / openssh-server 9.2p1-2. It is worth noting that the output of ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms includes ssh-rsa, so it is allowed on the server. The key was not accepted after upgrading from Debian 11 to Debian 12. It works with PuTTY 0.78.

Comment: @BoyanAlexiev `ssh -Q` tells you what is _implemented_, and only on _your system_ (not the server unless you run it _on_ the server). What is _allowed_ is only a subset of what is implemented (which _could_ be allowed if you change the configuration).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The command was run on the server. The original question states that "SSH server gives ... ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms". The idea was to point out that the issue is not on the server itself, i.e. the message is incorrect. There is no need to change the configuration to allow ssh-rsa.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing the [answers from @bk2204](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722049/377345) (RSA now requiring SHA-2) and [Giacomo Catenazzi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/746324/377345) (upgrading PuTTY to version 0.78), the explanation can be found in PuTTY's changelog for version 0.75:

> Support for RSA key algorithms using SHA-2 instead of SHA-1.

So PuTTY prior to version 0.75 attempted to use RSA with SHA-1, which is disabled by default on newer OpenSSH versions.